# Post Request on fastify, content-lenght missing FastifyError "code":"FST_ERR_CTP_EMPTY_JSON_BODY"

Tags: fastify

I am sending a POST request without a 'Content-Length' header using Postman (body is not empty). On a Fastify Server, I am getting an error response like this:

{"statusCode":400},"err":{"type":"FastifyError","message":"Body cannot be empty when content-type is set to 'application/json'","stack":"FastifyError: Body cannot be empty when content-type is set to 'application/json'

Is it possible to deactivate Content-Length on the Fastify server for incoming requests?"

Comment: I think you can't disable it - you need to write a custom content type parser: https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/ContentTypeParser/#content-type-parser